# Create a more user friendly display. My idea, is it possible?

Tags: c#, winforms

I was working on my program and I though about changing output into more user friendly display of data. Currently I am using a text box which simply prints out all information. I want to change it because I want delete button next to each record, which can not be used with text boxes, I think.

I was thinking of a display with rows, of some sort, that stretch though main window. Each row will display everything that my display should show, but Entry ID. Each row must be able to disappear and appear depending if entry was deleted or added.

Do you get an idea there?

Is there a way to display each data with row like looking display? Which tool in VS I could use to do this?

This is how I display data now:

[image]

Comment: I think you want a DataGridView

Comment: This question probably belongs on [UX](http://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Danny: I don't think datagridview would be a good idea. My output would look like MS Access rows and columns, which I am using to store my actual data, kill my purpose of the program if it looks like MS Access itself lol.

Comment: @LarsTech: I'm not a fan of betas. I believe this question does fit in this forum. I need a specific solution how to use VS and WinForms to find a new way of displaying a data.

Comment: Use WPF.  This is the sort of thing that it excels at!  :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "Entry" items look like they have different properties based on the image.  Entry ID #2 has four items while the other ones have three.  Based on that, you can use a `ListBox` with a `DrawMode = OwnerDrawVariable`.

Simple ListBox example:

```
private List<int> entries = new List<int>();

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();

  entries.Add(3);
  entries.Add(4);
  entries.Add(3);

  listBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
  listBox1.MeasureItem += new MeasureItemEventHandler(listBox1_MeasureItem);
  listBox1.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(listBox1_DrawItem);
}

private void listBox1_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Index > -1)
    e.ItemHeight = (((int)listBox1.Items[e.Index]) * 16) + 8;    
}

private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e) {
  e.DrawBackground();

  if (e.Index > -1) {
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D(e.Graphics, e.Bounds);
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)listBox1.Items[e.Index]; i++) {
      TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics,
                            "Item #" + i.ToString(),
                            e.Font,
                            new Point(e.Bounds.Left + 4, (e.Bounds.Top + 4) + (i * 16)),
                            Color.Black);
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't look bad at all, I didn't know I could do that in list box.